# Java. Несколько вопросов по Scene Builder

Tags: java, функции

1. Если есть годная методичка по работе с Scene Builder прошу скиньте.
2. Есть радио-кнопки как привязать их к коду?
   То есть там есть значение False в в файле *.fxml
   mnemonicParsing="false" но как с ним взаимодействовать непонятно
3. В этом же файле *.fxml существует у меня 
   поля TableView, что означает таблицу и columns, что означает колонки соответственно, но как добавить туда свою информацию я так же не понимаю, мне нужно как то свои ячейки прописывать в этих полях.
4. Возможно это поможет. Я пишу программу, которая решает уравнение исходя из данных. У меня есть 2 переменных А и Х, от которых и зависит ответ.
   https://ibb.co/kgJ5Dhn
   [image: Изначальное задание, которое я пытаюсь выполнить]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/index.html

Comment: https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/